# How to set id to a Grid generated by GridMvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hi guys I have an issue with grid mvc (GridMvc 3.0), the problem is who I can put and id like "grid1" or something like that, because I want to freeze the header and the only form I have found is with .freezeHeader() but I need to put an Id/Name to the grid/table.

```
<div>
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(col =>
{
    col.Add(m => m.NumeroEmpleado).Titled("Usuario").Filterable(true);
    col.Add(m => m.Nombre).Titled("Nombre Completo").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);         
})
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this page, you can add html attributes in "Attributed" element:

http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/HtmlAttributes

```
@model IEnumerable<PersonModel>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
        columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");
    })
    .Attributed(new { id = "your_id" })
)
```

Comment: I have tryit but it looks like the "Build" doesnt work or my version doesnt have that function, Im using MVC 4!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier solution for this but here is a tested alternative. Add an Html field. Add attributes id and style into it. Then assign col id to id attribute and "display:none" to style attribute. Now, you should have a hidden element with ID on each row. Then simply get the parent "tr" element of this hidden element to freeze.

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(col =>
{
    col.Add().RenderValueAs(r => @Html.Textbox("RowId","", new { id=r.Id style="display:none"}).ToString());
    col.Add(m => m.NumeroEmpleado).Titled("Usuario").Filterable(true);
    col.Add(m => m.Nombre).Titled("Nombre Completo").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);         
})
```